# I am getting an error when trying to create a many to many relationship using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a flask website and the database is queried using flask-sqlalchemy.
The following is the code that is returning the error:

```
post_tags = db.Table('post_tags',
    metadata_obj,
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True),
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)
)
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    # post_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tags', secondary=post_tags, backref='posts')
class Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=True)
```

Posts and tags have a many to many relationship so I used db.Table instead of db.Model for post_tags.
The following is the whole error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Posts->posts'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Posts.tags - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'post_tags'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.
```

Please help me out with this error!